# check htaccess %{HTTP_REFERER} is exist or empty?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem. I prevent hotlinking via htaccess in use of `%{HTTP_REFERER}`. Hotlinking is a nasty matter. Browsers can deactivate the Referer, and than it is empty. That is one of the problem, but not really mine. When in the browser the Referer is not deactivated: My problem is, when a user write a page URL directly in the addressbar or with copy&paste or use a link in a local ressource (like notepad++. or thunderbird?), also don't use a HTML link element in a document in the Internet, than the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` is seemingly not empty, because the hotlinking RewriteCond in the htaccess don't match, but the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is `Undefined`.

> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in /path...

But, the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` is emtpy! I have test it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} . [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?HTTP_REFERER=%{HTTP_REFERER} [L,R]
```

The query string: ?HTTP_REFERER=

Why is it not matched with this RewriteCond?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
```

An empty Referer is seemingly not a empty Referer. Sorry, i am a little bit confused with that.

EDIT1: Oh how I love it! I test and think and think and I couldn't think of a solution and then write a question and then I think of one!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "" # for really empty Referer!
```

Is this a correct solution? I'm not a specialist.
Edit2: It is not a solution. I am really confused. I have no idea.

EDIT3: Is there a difference between %{HTTP_REFERER} is exist or is empty?

EDIT4: Testcode. I am really confused and have no idea.

First: You must have a `DirectoryIndex index.html`.

Second: You must have a `test.php` and a `test.png`.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo PHP_EOL . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
if (is_null($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { echo "IS NULL"; }
echo PHP_EOL . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
echo PHP_EOL . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/">https://www.example.com/</a>';
echo PHP_EOL . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<img src="test.png">';
echo PHP_EOL . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Third: The `.htaccess` (with difficult conds to test)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "!test\.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "!\.png"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?x=%{HTTP_REFERER} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ""
#RewriteCond stringcomp "%{HTTP_REFERER} == ''"
#RewriteCond comp "'%{HTTP_REFERER}' !~ 'm#(.+)(\.)(.+)#i'"
RewriteRule "\.(png)$" "-" [F,L,NC]
```

It's not perfect. I don't known it better.
Yet call the https://www.example.com/ without linking, also directly in the browser address bar. Second time, you can click the link in the page for the second result.

The results of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$` and `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ""` are not the same.

Last: test it with deactivated Referer in the browser. Firefox: `about:config` → `network.http.sendRefererHeader` = 0.

The Problem: Catch empty Referer, but in apache an "empty" Referer is not a "empty" Referer. When the RewriteCond with RewriteRule `[F]` is catched, then use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to display a info message in the Webpage like "Images are only display with activated Referer". The problem by this: an empty Referer as a result of direct call ist not the same as an empty Referer because of deactivated Referer.

Edit5: Make more tests.
Append this in the `test.php`.

```
echo PHP_EOL . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . PHP_EOL;
```

.hatccess Info: the order of the conds with `%{HTTP_REFERER}` change the result with deactivated Referer.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "!test\.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "!\.png"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(png)$ "-" [F,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?x=%{HTTP_REFERER} [NC,L]
```

This order with deactivated Referer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?x=%{HTTP_REFERER} [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(png)$ "-" [F,NC,L]
```

Result: The first is matched, the second not. Because, the first RewriteRule perform a loop and than seemingly the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` is no longer empty. Consider: The Referer is furthermore empty `?x=`. Yes, it's empty, but no, it's not empty. It's crazy!

This order with deactivated Referer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(png)$ "-" [F,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?x=%{HTTP_REFERER} [NC,L]
```

Result: both are matched, because the loop is performing after the first and on both points the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` is empty.

With activated Referer becomes an another result. Thats too much for mee to report it.

Info: apache 2.4.

Comment: You apparently tried to be as detailed as possible here, but in fact I think you made the whole thing rather confusing, by adding this much info, and in so many different “oh now I discovered something new” steps. // I don’t think `""` in your condition did what you think it would - this is still treated as a regular expression, it would need to be `=""` if you wanted it to be a string comparison.

Comment: And with your first test, `$1?HTTP_REFERER=%{HTTP_REFERER} [L,R]`, I don’t think using the `R` flag there is a good idea, because you might lose the referrer on your own redirect _from_ your site _to_ your site there. This test should use an internal rewrite only.

Comment: eventually i am a littlte bit closer to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395182/match-http-referer-multiple